# how can i get one type of address in this object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

am using this to get recent transactions from blockchain

```
var bitcoin = new BLT();
bitcoin.connect();
bitcoin.events.on('tx', function (tx) {
    console.log(tx);
})
```

the result i get is this

```
{ txid:
 '481add86dc88db3d138cbc314d4d82ed08ca5db9cfdf5caff820e888996a5716',
valueOut: 0.00061956,
vout:
 [ { '19aFCo1n8qbUdxc35EAzWDFRCvbh7UwB4v': 600 },
   { '1L8Nkw16tQH3FHwLcVG2G2FXcrMjzJwXnQ': 61356 } ],
isRBF: false }
```

and i want to get one type of address.i have tried `tx.vout` which gives me both addresses and i want only one without the values after :

Comment: Both the values in vout contains value after : ?

Comment: All objects have values after `:`.

Comment: i mean the values in the vout section.the intergers after the addresses

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth Maybe what they mean is they want just the property name, without the corresponding value.

Comment: Do you only wants the key "19aFCo1n8qbUdxc35EAzWDFRCvbh7UwB4v", "1L8Nkw16tQH3FHwLcVG2G2FXcrMjzJwXnQ" from objects?

Comment: You mean sth. like ````Object.keys(tx.vout)[0]````? If so. I'd guess you should read more about JavaScript Objects. For the values as stated in your comment, you then could use ````Object.values(tx.vout)[0]````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` to get all the property names, and then index it with `[0]` to get the first property. Similarly, index `tx.vout` to get it from the first object in the array.

```js
tx = {
  txid: '481add86dc88db3d138cbc314d4d82ed08ca5db9cfdf5caff820e888996a5716',
  valueOut: 0.00061956,
  vout: [{
      '19aFCo1n8qbUdxc35EAzWDFRCvbh7UwB4v': 600
    },
    {
      '1L8Nkw16tQH3FHwLcVG2G2FXcrMjzJwXnQ': 61356
    }
  ],
  isRBF: false
}
console.log(Object.keys(tx.vout[0])[0]);
```

Comment: thanks but i want to get only one address like `'1L8Nkw16tQH3FHwLcVG2G2FXcrMjzJwXnQ'` as a string

Comment: You said in a comment that you want the integers.

Comment: I updated the answer to return the key of the first object.